# Creating a space for Graphics2D drawings

Tags: java, swing, graphics2d, boxlayout

I want to draw a simple board made of Graphics2D rectangles but I also want to have one JButton under this board. I know the exact dimensions of this board in pixels and I was trying to deal with `getContentPane()` method and BoxLayout, like this:

```
frame.getContentPane().add(board);
frame.getContentPane().add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(bWidth, bHeight)));
frame.getContentPane().add(new JButton("Start"));
frame.pack();
```

But RigidArea isn't truly invisible and it overrides my drawings. Could you please give me some tips how to make it work properly? :( I wanted just one little button and it made me sit here for around 2 hours now...

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to draw a simple board made of Graphics2D rectangles

When you do custom painting you also need to override the `getPreferredSize(...)` method of your component to return the size of the comoponent.

Then the layout manager can use this information and you will not need to use the rigid area.

When you add the components to the frame you can just use the default BorderLayout:

```
frame.add(board, BorderLayout.CENTER);
frame.add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

I suggest you read the [Swing tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html). There are section on `custom painting` and `using layout managers` that will provide more detail and examples.

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly what I was asking for! Now everything works perfect. :)
Well, it seems like a good start as a new user on this site... :)